# How to check mobile network range in android via programatically

Tags: android, mobile, network-programming, range

hi friends i want to check programmetically that device range if it is in range  then want to show message to user that you are in range of mobile network thnks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The API you'll need for doing that is [android.telephony.SignalStrength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html) which contains phone signal strength related information.

It's available from API level 7, that is Android 2.1.x or newer.